# magento2 save form to core_config_data

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am using magento2. I have form with few "ui_components" fields, lets say: `field1`, `field2` ,`field3` and `Save` button
How can I save values that was enter to all fields to core_config_data?

regarding core_config_data I know that I have to use this, to save data there:
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

```
/**
 *  @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface
 */
protected $configWriter;

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
 */
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $configWriter
    .....
)
{
    $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
}
```

and for calling method :

```
$this->configWriter->save('my/path/whatever',  $value, $scope =ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
```

I know each of the fields have its own fieldID, but how to use it to get data from it?

and how to save each of the fields values into separate core config row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is the same saveConfig method: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/ResourceModel/Config.php#L26-L61

A usage example from the core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Payment/Observer/UpdateOrderStatusForPaymentMethodsObserver.php#L59-L64

Source :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92917/magento-2-programmatically-add-a-value-to-core-config-data

Comment: Thanks for answer regarding saveConfig, but how to take values from fields of my form?

Answer (score 0):

You can post your values in the controller class and save into core_config_data table.